# Request callback URL from webmail when new mail received

Tags: email, cpanel, webhooks, webmail

I am using my domain mail "example@demo.com". I am receiving query mails over it. Now I have to insert some data in my DB when new mail will be received on this "example@demo.com" webmail address. My question is that is there any webmail webhook or another way to call the decided URL. The purpose of this I have to send confirmation message to user.